# Looking for a Good Text on Statistical Analysis of Satisfaction Data

Tags: regression, likert, validation

I am looking for a good textbook (or other resource) that covers the analysis of satisfaction data.  Most of my data uses likert-type scales.  Can anyone recommend something with examples?

Comment: There may be a textbook on nothing but the analysis of satisfaction data, but it strikes me as somewhat unlikely. If you are just wondering about how to analyze data from likert scales, you could read the threads on CV categorized under the [tag:likert] tag. There are a lot of them. If a particular issue hasn't been covered, you could ask a new question here about it.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Analysis-Customer-Satisfaction-Derek-Allen/dp/0873894537 have a look at this book